# React Native Push Notification onRegister token is null

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-push, react-native-push-notification

I am using zo0r [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library.

For some reason, when i open the `app` for the first time after i installed it on the mobile device (`iOS` or `Android`) the token is returned as null.

```
    PushNotification.configure({

onRegister: function(token) {
    console.log( 'TOKEN:', token );
},

onNotification: function(notification) {
    console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );
},

senderID: "YOUR GCM SENDER ID",

permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true
},

popInitialNotification: true,
requestPermissions: true, 
});
```

My question is, which is the best approach to get the token if the onRegister method returns token as null?
Do i have to recall this function in other screen of the app?

```
 "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
 "react-native": "^0.44.3",
 "react-native-push-notification": "^3.0.1"
```

Thank you for your help,

Mikhi

Comment: I have  done push notification using FCM in react-native. If you need any help related to that then I can help you.

Comment: Hi Deepak, thanks for your message. The push notification feature is working for both versions of the app. The open/remaining issue is that i described above.

Comment: yes, It works for both.

Comment: Did you use the same package for push notifications?

Comment: Are you asking about same package for firebase configuration ?

Comment: yes, i'm asking if you use the same package. if not, what package did you use?

Comment: This question is closed...i found some workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I don't know why but **PushNotification.configure** does not work on iOS, so you should use

```
const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
if (fcmToken) {
// user has a device token
} else {
// user doesn't have a device token yet
}
```

instead of PushNotification.configure, (do not forget to use **async** if you use **await**), or another way:

```
firebase.messaging().getToken()
.then(fcmToken => {
 if (fcmToken) {
  // user has a device token
 } else {
  // user doesn't have a device token yet
 } 
});
```

And for Android, the method I sent o above does not work. But PushNotification.configure works. You should use PushNotification.configure to get tokens for android. You should check your SDK, firebase-messaging versions and should update your android studio because old version of Android studio does not suppport of new version firebase-messaging. After I did these things I got my tokens successfully on Android. If you have some troubles to update these things I can send you all details of versions and how to update them.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was `FCM.getAPNSToken()` runs right after `FCM.requestPermissions()`, so application didn't get permissions for push notifications when method runs.

Change:

```
componentDidMount -> async componentDidMount
```

and

```
FCM.requestPermissions(); -> await FCM.requestPermissions();
```

This solution is https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/528